# How to disable Directory Browse in Web.Config

Tags: asp.net, iis, web-config

I have a WebSite and I woud like **Deny Directory Browser** from a **web.config file**.

Here the code I'm using placed in the ROOT.
Does not work. I'm testing it Locally so with URL LIKE http://localhost:3214/ I can still browser the directory fro CMS.

- What I'm doing wrong?
- Should it work even on Local Machine?

Thanks for your support!

```
<configuration>
  <location path="Cms">
    <system.webServer>
      <directoryBrowse enabled="false" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

Some resource:

http://blogs.iis.net/bills/archive/2008/03/24/how-to-enable-directory-browsing-with-iis7-web-config.aspx

http://www.expta.com/2008/03/configuring-virtual-directories-with.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First: not everything works in a `<location>` block.

I cannot find a positive statement that `<system.webServer>` isn't supported in a `<location>`, but I cannot find any cases where it is suggested that it is allowed. Evidence for this is in the (global) `machine.config` where the `system.webserver` section is defined to use the `IgnoreSection` handler: ie. it isn't processed by the standard `System.Configuration` implementation, and it is that standard implementation of config handling that provides support for `<location>`.

Try adding a `web.config` into the `Cms` folder with the `directoryBrowse` element to confirm that browsing is blocked.

Answer (score 6):

Gibbok, nothing is wrong here, Don't panic :)

Assuming that you are browsing your website from the built-in server inside Visual Studio, This is typically a normal case.

I'm pretty sure that if you moved to IIS with the above code, Directory browsing will behave just like what you want it to be.

Give it a try and host this website in IIS, and let us know what happened, Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I was trying the same code. What you have is in fact correct. Here is the [reference](http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/directoryBrowse).

Of course it wasn't working for me and I couldn't figure out why, until I read Richard's post and remembered that someone put a web.config file in that directory. That file overrides the behavior in the main web.config file. In the sub directory web.config the directoryBrowse option was explicitly turned on (as well as a LOT of other handlers, yikes!). Delete that file and what you have above works for me. It actually passes the request along to the next handler, which is exactly what I wanted.

I'm using IIS 7 on my local machine.

Answer (score 0):

the <directoryBrowse> directive controls the listing of the directory via the http protocol only: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms691327%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

It will not have any effect on code, trying to access the directory from within any other (or even your own) application.

@Edit: after the edit and if I get you right - I think, what you mean by *Deny Directory Browser* is the intended functionality: show the contents of the dir within a specified path using the browser. And yes, it probably will not work in the local development server. Try it on IIs!

Comment: At the moment I'm using built-in server inside Visual Studio. Do you think would work on IIS?