# How to avoid directory listing

Tags: asp.net, url-routing

Please help to avoid directory listing while running asp.net application ,(NavigateUrl="<%$ RouteUrl:Routename=**Example**%>") Folder name is also **Example** in which the page contains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you please glance over [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5549374/how-to-disable-directory-browse-in-web-config) and also it could be done in IIS->site->"Directory Browsing"

Comment: Its working while adding in default document, but not working in local host, working fine in server

Comment: Have you tried add <system.webServer>
      <directoryBrowse enabled="false" />
    </system.webServer> to yours web.config file?

Comment: Thanks for your help.Its working after added default document in web.config but its working fine in live sever , not working in local host