# Running Web API and MVC projects simultaneously

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-web-api

So I have two projects: a Web API service and MVC web site which consumes service, both in one solution. I considered to run them using multiple startup projects option, but encountered a problem. Since Web API has no web interface, it opens in browser and lists contents of project directory. How can I prevent this?

Comment: do you debug your web api project in visual studio or deploy it to IIS ?

Comment: Prevent.. what? You don't want to open a webpage for the web api? Why don't you just close it?

Comment: also consider this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5549374/how-to-disable-directory-browse-in-web-config

Comment: You can add a default controller/action that returns an empty view or add a `default.htm` to the root of the Web API project. If you don't want the web page to display you could try running IISExpress from the command line http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/using-iis-express/running-iis-express-from-the-command-line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't want the browser window to open every time you run the project you can change your Web Api project properties.

Go to Properties > Web and select "Don't open a page. Wait for a request from an external application" under the 'Start Action' heading, this will keep the project running in the background.

See answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/716757

Comment: Nice find.. Not all of us get a chance to read complete Visual Studio documentation.